# Python Tkinter Enter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to store the values of a Tkinter text box widget as a string to use in the rest of my code. But every time I have an enter function I am getting errors regarding the defying of the command is not possible in the `functionCall`.

```
class text():
    master = Tk()
    def on_button():
        print()
        t = Label(master, text="Enter Text ")
        e1 = Text(master, width=50, height = 25)
        e1.grid(row=0, column =1, rowspan=3, columnspan=4, padx=4, pady=4)
        functionCall = Button(master, text='Enter', command=Return)
        functionCall.grid(row=4, column=4)
    var = StringVar()
    def Return(self):
        self.TempVar=self.Entry.get()
        print(self.TempVar)
```

I am trying to connect the string inserted with the rest of my code. The concept works with a one-line entry box, but the idea is to have a bigger text box.

Comment: what are the errors that you are getting? The error likely tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You are creating a root window inside the `text(0` function -- is this the only place you're creating a root window? There seems to be a lot of code missing, since you don't show how the `on_button` function is being called.

Comment: This is the function to make a pop up window for the user to insert text. The rest of the code correlates based off of what is typed in the window by putting every key to a color window to show in a window. But the idea is to have the code go through the while loop:
while index < len(name):
   letter = name[index]
   num = ord(letter)
   stack.append(num)
   index += 1  @BryanOakley The error is object of type 'NoneType has no len()

Comment: You need to use a `Toplevel`, not another instance of `Tk`. That may not be your only problem, but it's definitely _a_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that. You would use `.get` option for `Text` widget.

```
from tkinter import*
master = Tk()
def on_button():
   print()

def Return():
   TempVar=e1.get("1.0",END)
   print(TempVar)

t = Label(master, text="Enter Text ")
t.grid(row=0, column =1, rowspan=3, columnspan=4, padx=4, pady=4)
e1 = Text(master, width=50, height = 25)
e1.grid(row=1, column =1, rowspan=3, columnspan=4, padx=4, pady=4)
functionCall = Button(master, text='Enter', command=Return)
functionCall.grid(row=4, column=4)
```

Comment: In terms of a length value within the string, would that be able to be recognized?

Comment: You wrote _"You should try something like that."_ -- like _what_? What does "that" refer to in that sentence?

Comment: Oh, oh. So, more like "you should try something like the following code..."?